# How to remove all unicode characters from a blob?

Tags: apex, callout, csv, blob, parser

I have a requirement to parse the contents of a csv blob which has unicode characters. When I am trying to parse it using

`Blob myBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(response.getBody())`

I am getting an exception saying -

```
"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Unrecognized base64 character: \u0003"
```

What would be the correct way to parse this blob ?

Comment: Is the response even encoded as base64? If it's not, you could simply `.toString()` the blob.

Answer (score 0):

The getBody method returns the CSV data as a UTF-8 string. No additional parsing necessary.

```
String csvString = response.getBody();
```

If you wanted a blob, use getBodyAsBlob.

```
Blob csvBlob = response.getBodyAsBlob();
```

Regardless, if your file has non-UTF-8 characters, you won't be able to read it as UTF-8. You'll need to check the data you're receiving to make sure it's in the proper format.